# Measure (CALCULATE) - two fact tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi DAX Experts around the world,

I hope you can help me with below problem. In short:

- there are two fact tables: **Table1** and **Table2** , not connected between each other and cannot be appended.
- they have both relation to Calendar table
- I need to create a measure which will return some part from **Table1** and a part form **Table2**, as described on the picture.
- When a Nov-21 is selected on the slicer, measure should return Actuals for first 10 months of the year with 100 each month (from **Table1**) and remaining 2 months with Forecast values from with 200 each month (from **Table2**).

Is it possible at all as I am out of ideas ?

Thank you in advance.
Max

[image]

Comment: do you expect the values to display all 12 rows, or just need to calculate the total?

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of `DAX`? Do you want to calculate a `SUM` or `MAX`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the calendar table(`Calender (2)`), which can be used to create a slicer.

With the help of this table, you can create a measure to calculate the value based on selected date like this:

```
Amount Measure = 
VAR _selected_date = MAX('Calender (2)'[Date])
return SUMX(SUMMARIZE(Calender,Calender[Date]),IF('Calender'[Date]<_selected_date,SUMX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Version]="Actual"),[Amount]),SUM(Table2[Amount])))
```

Comment: If the provided solution has solved your issue, can you please mark it as an answer